# How to add location info to Calendar using "Quick Event"

Tags: macos, calendar, ical

In OS X Yosemite Calendar, I can quickly add an event by pressing Cmd-N and typing "lunch tomorrow 1-3pm at McDonalds".  But how can I set a location?  In this example, the event title will be "lunch at McDonalds" and the location will by blank.

For example, these attempts at providing parsing hints do not work:

```
Attempted Text -> 'Interpreted Event title' [Interpreted event time]

Movie Friday 7pm at 1 Infinite Loop -> 'Movie Friday 7pm Infinite Loop' [1pm today]
Movie, 1 Infinite Loop, Friday 7pm  -> 'Movie, 1 Infinite Loop,' [Fri 7pm]
Movie at 1 Infinite Loop, Friday 7pm -> 'Movie at 1 Infinite Loop,' [Fri 7pm]
Movie, location:1 Infinite Loop, on Friday at 7pm -> 'Movie, location:1 Infinite Loop,' [Fri 7pm]
```

(The desired outcome is an event with title 'Movie', time Friday at 7pm, location '1 Infinite Loop'.)

Is there some syntax or hint for the app to parse the quick event text to populate the location field?

Comment: @Philip This question is asking about Yosemite, probably because it's almost 1y old.  Are you still interested in Yosemite only or will an answer for El Capitan work for you?

Comment: This will happen if location services is not turned on, can you check in your system preferences if the calendar has location services turned on ? also are you located outside the US ?

Comment: @fbara I'm on El Capitan; an up-to-date answer is ideal.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg I do have location services on in US; I think you may be misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. I (and I presume OP) just want to populate a field in the event details with plain text; this should not require location services. (I agree that using the auto-complete to get an actual mapped location would require location services.)

Comment: After reading your answer to @MostafaTorbjørnBerg I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking for.  My understanding of the OP's question is to be able to type the location in Quick Event and have the calendar use that as the location in the calendar entry.  Are you saying you want to enter the location but not have it treated as an actual location and just treated as plain text?

Comment: I would like to use plain text locations, but real location-based addresses would be fine too.

Comment: @Philip / Elliott I have grappled with this same problem for a while and have arrived at the conclusion that there is no way to get this working (not what you guys want to hear, I know). My solution is to wait for the confirmation inspector to pop up, and then press tab and enter my location there. Just an extra keystroke.

Comment: I must be missing something with this one.  I can enter 'Breakfast at McDonalds on 87th Street' into a quick event and I get that exact same text as the title of my calendar entry without any location info.  If I'm reading the question and comments right, that's what you're looking to do? I'm on 10.11.6.

Comment: @fbara no -- they want the location to show up in the location field.

Comment: Thanks @ruddfawcett, I was totally confused on this for some reason.

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion; @ruddfawcett is right. I've updated the question with an example to make that more clear [edit is awaiting peer review as of this moment]. Thx

Comment: @ruddfawcett If consensus after a day or two is that you're right / there's no way to do it, perhaps you should add as answer to get the bounty. Of course if Apple ever implements the feature, Elliott and I will look forward to your updated answer :)

Comment: @Philip cheers!

Comment: @Philip completely misread your "after a day or two." I'll just leave my answer up in the meantime, and specific comments about it can be added to the answer itself.

Comment: @philip I think you're wrong, iCal supports this, it's in the documentation found here : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202835, it specifically states that exact feature in The quick event field paragraph!, which requires location services to be on, I would say this is a bug if it doesn't automatically populate the location field from your natural text input

Comment: After looking into the system logs while creating a new event, i notice that this error is being logged:
`Aug  3 09:11:58 Mac-Mini Calendar[50774]: Could not launch query, mds might have an issue`

mds is spotlight's metadata server, I'm getting pretty sure that this is a bug, looking into more details now

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg kudos--this is good factfinding. Look forward to hearing what else you find. LMK if I can test something on my machine. As I mentioned I have location services on and am in the US....

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Any more news? I plan to award the bounty to Rudd, unless you have new proof that I should not.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg All right, well, ship is sailing but I hope that doesn't discourage you from reporting if you do find anything. Best & thanks all

Comment: @Philip Sorry was offline during the weekend, but I haven't found anything more than what i discovered, tried it on several other macs on different networks and they all reproduced the same bug, hopefully apple will get to fix this and i'll surely put a new answer when i find something new !, thanks:)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know (and I'm purposefully not citing anything here, because I have found absolutely nothing on the topic after much Googling, other searching, etc.), as of El Capitan there **is no way to achieve this**.

My rather simple workaround is to type out my event, such as

> Dinner with Will on Wednesday at 7 PM

And then to quickly <kbd>tab</kbd> to the location field in the event inspector, and fill in the event's location there there, e.g.:

[image: Creating a quick event without a location.]
[image: Quickly tab to location field and fill it out there.]

---

Happy to update this answer as a more fulfilling solution presents itself.

Comment: I hope my answer below can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer at this [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3810526) thread from 2012 mentioned downloading [Remind Me Later](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remind-me-later/id408236729?mt=12), free from the App Store, and simply typing "at" and then specifying  the location.

[image: Screenshot of Remind Me Later]

Comment: If the link ever goes dead, the thread is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170817143124/https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3810526